# Can I use 2.5kW solar panels to power 2kW rated grid tie solar inverter?

Tags: solar-power

Can I use 2.5kW solar panels (10x 250 watts) to power 2kW rated grid tie solar inverter? Will anything blow up?

Panels: 10x 250W, 36V panels

Inverter: 2kW with max input voltage: 500V

any help is appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Can you provide make/model of the inverter? The panel rating will be max supply to inverter, and inverter rating will be max supply to the grid. It will not draw more from the panels than it can use to supply.

Comment: Actually, I see you also [posted this on Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486006/can-i-use-2-5kw-solar-panels-to-power-2kw-rated-grid-tie-solar-inverter). The answer there is correct, but more detail might help you get a more specific answer.

Comment: You need to make sure that you donot exceed the maximum input DC voltage that the invertor can handle. The 36 Volts specified for panel is the nominal voltage at capacity. Open circuit voltage can be higher then that by 10 to 20%.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a very good plan.**

Nothing will blow up. The inverter will just cap production to 2 kW.

I think you'll find that most locations except the equator have smaller production in the winter. Production early in the morning or late in the evening is low, too. Clouds also lower production during midday. Thus, the time when the panels are producing over 2 kW is very limited.

Generally, it is not economical to pair 2.5 kW panels with 2.5 kW inverter these times when solar cells are so cheap they cost almost nothing, and the cost of a solar installation is mainly based on the cost of the roof to install the panels on, and the cost of the installation labor. The times the panels are producing over 2 kW are so rare that the last dollars (the extra money that gave you the last 0.5 kW) you could invest in the 2.5 kW inverter would be used with a terribly low capacity factor.

In a very northern location where power is produced predominantly in the summer, you will find that it might make sense to pair 2.5 kW panels with even 1.5 kW inverter.